OpenCore Legacy Patcher - stuck during install
I have installed Monterey several times on iMac 21, Mid 2011 (A1311). Everything was running fine until it always got stuck after about the 4th restart - you can see the Apple symbol and the process symbol is one third of the way up (after about 2 to 3 hours, I cancel the installation and start from the beginning).
Any of you have any idea? :)
Thanks a lot.
John
I put a new Patriot P220 512GB SSD on the iMac (I thought the original HDD was the problem, but apparently not).
I created the installation USB on another iMac (OS Monterey), in the settings I set as Target Model iMac12.1 - according to support. I don't understand the other settings. :)
I also tried "Internet Recovery" - I formatted the SSD, connected to WiFi - the iMac downloaded something, restarted once, but then it stopped again for two hours.

Try booting into Safe-Mode while installing (press Shift before selecting Installation Drive). Apparently that helps.
Watch this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhQ7SWhRakU
